# How to change this design side by side?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

How to change this design side by side? I am trying to use Container, Column, and Row widgets. But after I insert the Widget Row design it won't come out and the screen freezes.
I hope someone can help me

Code:

```
 const SizedBox(height: 20),
                                const Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "My Vitals",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        height: 1.4,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 15,
                                ),
                                _bloodPressureLatest.isNotEmpty
                                    ? bloodPressureLatest(    <= Function for bloodPressure design
                                        context,
                                        checkBloodPressureReadingStatus(
                                            double.parse(_bloodPressureLatest[0]
                                                ["bloodPressure"]["systolic"])),
                                        _bloodPressureLatest[0]["bloodPressure"]
                                                ["systolic"] ??
                                            "0",
                                        _bloodPressureLatest[0]["bloodPressure"]
                                                ["diastolic"] ??
                                            "0",
                                        _bloodPressureLatest[0]
                                                ["recordTimestamp"] ??
                                            _timestamp)
                                    : bloodPressureLatest(
                                        context, 0, "0", "0", _timestamp),
                                _heartRateLatest.isNotEmpty
                                    ? heartRateLatest(  <= Function for heart rate design
                                        context,
                                        _heartRateLatest,
                                        _heartRateLatest[0]["vitalValue"],
                                        _heartRateLatest[0]["recordTimestamp"])
                                    : heartRateLatest(
                                        context, [], "0"
```

Comment: What do you mean side by side? Please describe because currently I can't understand what you want.

Comment: I can't tell where that list is.  is it in a row?

Answer (score 0):

wrap your elements in SizedBox() and give it a width. like :

```
Row(
 children: [
  SizedBox(
   width: 200,
   child: bloodPressureLatest(...),
  ),
  SizedBox(
   width: 200,
   child: heartRateLatest(...),
  ),
 ],
),
```